# hide label and conf. value in YOLOv5

Tags: python, pytorch, label, detection, yolov5

I loaded a model (local in my laptop). I tried to remove (hide) label and conf. value from images using (model.hide_labels = True) and (model.hide_conf = True). It didn't work.

How can I hide labels and conf. value? I only want boxes.

```
model = torch.hub.load('ultralytics/yolov5', 'custom', './yolov5s/best.pt')  # custom trained model
## Images
im = './Data/val/images/10_8.jpg'  # or file, Path, URL, PIL, OpenCV, numpy, list

model.hide_labels = True
model.hide_conf = True

## Inference
results = model(im)

## Results
results.show()  # or .show(), .save(), .crop(), .pandas(), print()
```

Comment: I solved it by using results.show(labels=False)

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by using results.show(**labels=False**)